# Showing that a sequence convergent to something using Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Here is my typical approach to showing a (recursive)sequence converges to something:

I show that the sequence is monotonically increasing or decreasing, and after that, I choose a very large upper bound or make the lower bound 0 to show that it is bounded. Then, I substitute $L$ for the recurrence relation and find $L$ to finish the proof(follows from monotone convergence theorem). However, my friends tend to try to show that the lower bound or upper bound is the thing they are trying to prove the sequence converges to, and it seems much more tedious than my way. I mean, they don't even show that it's the infimum or supremum, so generally, they have to sub in $L$ for the recurrence relation, and solve it using the method I used anyway.

For example, if I was asked to show that $x_k \rightarrow \sqrt{C}$, I would just show that the sequence is monotonically decreasing, and it's bounded by $0$, and then I do the limit substation to show that the sequence does indeed converge to $\sqrt{C}$. However, my friends would try to show that the sequence is bounded below by $\sqrt{C}$. This seems harder.

Am I misunderstanding something, and doing these problems incorrectly?

Thanks,
Rahul